# What is the right way to fetch data to Crypto/ Stock market application?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, frontend, fetch

I am making a CryptoCurrency project that fetch data from coingecko free API (https://www.coingecko.com/en/api/documentation), my project repo is here: https://github.com/HigorR456/crypto-tiger and  you can see the website online here: https://crypto-tiger.netlify.app/

In CryptoCurrency or Stock Market websites or apps you can see that the prices of each stock/ currency changes everytime as it goes up or down, it means that I need to fetch it everytime, for example, take a look at this website I took as inspiration to do mine: https://coinmarketcap.com/ you can see that the prices are updating each second.

In my project I set it to fetch each 20 seconds using setInterval method (anything lower than that set error 429 that is too many requests), and it works just one time, the price changes only one time, if I wait 300 seconds or update the page it will work again (the prices will update again). https://crypto-tiger.netlify.app/
``
This is the first fetch, it is done on page loading using getStaticProps from nextjs:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const response = await fetch('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=10&page=1&sparkline=false&locale=en')
  if (!response.ok) {
    console.log('Error', response.status)
  }
  const data = await response.json()
  return {
    props: {data}
  }
}
```

The function below is called each 20 seconds through setInterval.

```
async function getUpdate() {
    console.log('fetch')
    const response = await fetch('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=10&page=1&sparkline=false&locale=en')
    const data = await response.json()
    return data
  }
```

This is the setInterval function that calls the function getUpdate (above) each 20 seconds:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let interval = setInterval(async () => {
      console.log('setInterval');
      let data = [];
      try {
        data = await getUpdate();
        setList(data);
        console.log('data was setted')
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error', err);
      }
    }, 20000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);
```

and it apparently works as each console.log is logged in the console.

After that the list state is updated and it is rendered again making the animation function runs again as it returns the id (the animation turn colors from red/green/ grey to white as it goes up down or keeps the same) through this function.

```
const handleUpdateEffect = (price: any, i: any) => {
    if (prevList.length === 1) {
      console.log('prevlist length equal 1')
      return ''
    } else if (price > prevList[i].current_price) {
      console.log(price - prevList[i].current_price);
      return 'current-price-down'
    } else if (price < prevList[i].current_price) {
      console.log(price - prevList[i].current_price);
      return 'current-price-up'
    } else {
      console.log(price - prevList[i].current_price);
      return 'current-price-keep'
    }
  }
```

I put console logs in each if option and it logs the price difference between each crypto in the first fetch but after that it only returns me 0, giving me the information that there is no price difference. I know this difference through usePrevious hook I created using useRef, it storage the previous state of list:

```
export function usePrevious(value: any) {
  const ref = useRef([{current_price: 0}]);
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  }, [value]);
  return ref.current;
}
```

I tried put many console.logs through the code to see if there is anything wrong with the code and apparently seems ok as everything is logged in the console. So the only thing that comes to my mind is that this free API only updates data each 300 seconds or when you update the page but I don't understang why and if it is the case I would like to know why, because it doen't make sense to me that if I update the page it works the first time and if I stay in the page it spends 300 seconds to work again.

I also would like to know if the way I am fetching the data to update the prices using setInterval and useRef to storage the previous state and compares it with the current is right, if there is someone who already worked at a project like this if the way I code it is right or if there is something to improve.

Comment: If you stay on your website for a few minutes, will the prices update at some point? Coingecko's public API has a "Data Freshness" of "5 min+", meaning the data will be cached for a few minutes as you described

Comment: Yes, I've noticed the prices update every 300 seconds, but why when I press F5 to load the page again it updates immediately and once after 20 seconds (with my fetch update function I setted every 20 seconds) and then only after 300 seconds again. Does each function has different cache? If I have three functions will it be updated three times and then repeat after 300 seconds? Because I am using getStaticProps to do the first fetch and then another function to do another fetch every 20 seconds. Do you know if there is a way to bribe this cache thing or just if I create several functions?

Comment: are you sure it updates immediately after refresh? This would only be the case if the requests were cached on your browser, but if you do a request to e.g. https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin&vs_currencies=usd in Postman, you can see that the there's a response header of e.g. `Age: 319` and `Expires: Thu, 06 Apr 2023 12:34:59 GMT`, meaning it's actually cached on the server/CDN of coingecko and *not* your browser. So even if you refresh, there should still be the old value returned to you that only updates once every few minutes.

Comment: No, what you said is right, I just tested it and it goes back to the last value and then after 20 seconds update to the next, e.g. bitcoin price: 28040.00 and after 20 seconds goes to 28002.00, if I refresh the page it goes back to 28040.00 and updates to 28002.00 again after 20 seconds. Thank you for clarify that. Now the only remaining question is if the way I am fetching this data is right for a Crypto/Stock market application.

Comment: If you the price goes back after refreshing you have an issue with getStaticProps, I'll post an answer in a few minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to fetching the data, the way you're doing it right looks good on both server and client besides that now the prices will never update on the HTML that is being initially sent to the client because you use `getStaticProps` instead of `getServerSideProps` without ever revalidating the props from `getStaticProps`.

In your getStaticProps, you could do this:

```js
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const response = await fetch('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=10&page=1&sparkline=false&locale=en')
  if (!response.ok) {
    console.log('Error', response.status)
  }
  const data = await response.json()
  return {
    revalidate: 60 * 3 // refetch and updated the pre-rendered HTML every ~3 minutes
    props: {data}
  }
}
```

Now whenever someone visits the page after 3 minutes, the page will be re-built with updated data that will be included in the HTML sent to the client.

---

### Fallback in case you get rate-limited or coingecko is down

And I'm not sure if this is still the case on Netlify, but if you coingecko should be down or rate-limit you which could cause `getStaticProps` to crash, Netlify wouldn't return the previously, successfully built page with `getStaticProps` but rather makes your entire app crash.

So you could use basically any simple key-value-database like Redis (the free tier of Upstash redis is great for serverless https://upstash.com/) to save the most up-to-date data fetched to redis and retrieve it as a fallback.

```
npm i @upstash/redis
```

Get your upstash Redis url and token and add them to your `.env.local` as well as on netlify

```
UPSTASH_REDIS_REST_URL=<your_url>
UPSTASH_REDIS_REST_TOKEN=<your_token>
```

```js
import { Redis } from "@upstash/redis";

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const CACHE_KEY_NAME = "some-key-name";
  let data;
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=10&page=1&sparkline=false&locale=en"
    );
    if (!response.ok) {
      console.log("Error", response.status);
    }
    data = await response.json();

    // cache the successfully fetched data in case the next revalidation attempt fails
    await Redis.fromEnv().set(CACHE_KEY_NAME, data);
  } catch (err) {
    // coingecko fetching failed, serve data from cache instead
    const cachedData = await Redis.fromEnv().get(CACHE_KEY_NAME);
    data = cachedData || [];
  }
  return {
    revalidate: 60 * 3, // refetch and updated the pre-rendered HTML every ~3 minutes
    props: { data },
  };
}
```

Obviously you get get way more advanced, like having multiple fallback APIs or directly fetching from exchanges and aggregating the average price etc, but this should work for starters